# How can I make newline and align the equation of the math equation in CrossValidated?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, latex, newline

I want to input a math equation in CrossValidated like this:

[image: C_z(h)=Cov{Z(u), Z(u+h)}=\sum_{l=0}^{L}\sum_{k=0}^{L}a^la^kCov{Y^l(u),Y^k(u+h)}=\sum_{l=0}^{L}a^la^lc_l(h)]

But I want a version of vectorized latex equation, not an image like above (you can zoom in the webpage to validate it). When I input the equation like this: "$C_z(h)=Cov{Z(u),Z(u+h)}=\sum_{l=0}^{L}\sum_{k=0}^{L}a^la^kCov{Y^l(u),Y^k(u+h)}=\sum_{l=0}^{L}a^la^lc_l(h)$", it even did not work, neither considering make newlines and align equation symbol. In fact, I tried "//" for making newlines and "&=" for aligning equation symbols, but they don't work.

Comment: Are you following these examples: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27793/510296 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6267/510296 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5024/510296 ?

Comment: As noted, the canonical is the awesome *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)*.